# I can not get gSuite-Table last modified by in api V3 php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I want get all information last Modified User. with api V2 I can get them. but api V3 I can not.

```
$http = $client->authorize();
$revisions = $http->request(
'GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1UJOqL5yJiIQUG1YTK67MBikX_VT2hEppVTzlOhT1M7M/revisions');
$data = $revisions->getBody()->getContents();
$arrData = json_decode($data);
$arrRevisions = $arrData->revisions;
$logtime = $logTime = $arrRevisions[count($arrRevisions) - 1];
```

This is response api V3: https://prnt.sc/uqxren
This is response api V2: https://prnt.sc/uqxssi

Comment: why not you using the Google api php client?

Comment: Please dont include screen shots please include the actual code or response in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At Drive API v3, no all values are returned as the default returned values. So in this case, it is required to use `fields` parameter. In your case, how about adding `fields=*` to the endpoint as the query parameter as follows?

#### From:

```
$revisions = $http->request(
'GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1UJOqL5yJiIQUG1YTK67MBikX_VT2hEppVTzlOhT1M7M/revisions');
```

#### To:

```
$revisions = $http->request(
'GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1UJOqL5yJiIQUG1YTK67MBikX_VT2hEppVTzlOhT1M7M/revisions?fields=*');
```

#### Reference:

- [Revisions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list)

Comment: @Rafa Guillermo Thank you for your always support!

Comment: @Tran Trong Nham Phap Thank you for your response.